# How to determine whether ContactItem in Outlook is displayed or not (dispose properly)

Tags: vba, outlook

If the user has the contact open in an inspector then I want to save and `Set itm = Nothing` but not close the contact. If the contact is not open then I want to save and dispose.

```
Dim mfFolder As MAPIFolder
Set mfFolder = GetContactsFolder 'function to get folder

Dim itm As ContactItem
Set itm = mfFolder.Items.Find("[Account] = " & Chr(34) & AcctNum & Chr(34))
'or...
Set itm = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
'or...
Set itm = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
```

This closes the item which is fine if it is not open in an inspector:

```
Call itm.Close(olSave)
Set itm = Nothing
```

Or if the item is open in an inspector window then I want to save without closing:

```
Call itm.Save
Set itm = Nothing
```

So once I have the item, how do i determine whether it is open in an inspector window so I can dispose of it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, instead of calling Close(olSave), you can simply call ContactItem.Save - that will save the item wwithout closing it.

Secondly, you can compare the values of the EntryID property for the item that your code references and the item returned by Inspector.CurrentItem.

Comment: Actually I was hoping for something along the lines of itm.IsOpen or some way to tell if the item is open. I've found that Itm.Save followed by Set Itm = Nothing results in memory usage rising.